# Can I get Apple Mail app to automatically split emails into focused and other?

Tags: mac, mail.app, email

I've come from using Outlook which automatically splits my emails into "focused" and "other" (Gmail does something similar I believe) and am wondering if the Mac Mail app has similar functionality?  If it's useful to know, it's a hotmail account that I'm viewing in the Mail app.

Sorry if this is an obvious question - I couldn't find anything about this online.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Apple Mail on iOS nor macOS has this feature.

You could set up a rule on your mail server to move messages categorised as other to a folder which would then appear in Mail, but then the emails no longer appear in Other if you looked at your emails in another client or the web interface.

Comment: Meant to respond to this but got distracted and forgot about it until I opened my browser.  Thanks for responding so promptly, I guess I'll stick to my Outlook app on my phone/ipad for when I'm checking emails.